# Passing pointer to "class that inherits from A and B"

Tags: c++, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have several Abstract Base Classes which act like interfaces as known from Java or C#, let's say these are A, B and C.

Now I have some concrete classes, each implementing a subset of the interfaces:

```
class Concrete1: public A, public B
class Concrete2: public A, public C
class Concrete3: public A, public C
```

At some point I'd like to have a method which requires its argument to implement A and C (so it should be possible to pass Concrete2 und Concrete3).

I could do

```
class AC: public A, public C
class Concrete1: public A, public B
class Concrete2: public AC
class Concrete3: public AC
```

and accept a pointer to AC but I don't like this approach, because it might end at something like

```
class AC: public A, public C
class AB: public A, public B
class ABC: public A, public B, public C
class Concrete1: public AB
class Concrete2: public AC
class Concrete3: public AC
class Concrete4: public AC, public AB, public ABC
```

Is there any good alternative?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No good alternative exist, I think. Because this problem arose from mistakes at initial interface breakdown.

If its large burden, interfaces redesign is the real good alternative.

Or you could overcome with template method, dynamic_cast, blind C style cast. Or make to two methods for each interfaces.

Comment: you're right, it was a problem of how my interfaces were designed.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, if these are public abstract base classes and you expect to able to use them as interface types, they need to be virtual -- otherwise you will get duplicate bases and ambiguity problems.

That said, if you need to be able to accept something that is both an 'A' and a 'C' then there really is an 'AC' abstract base class, so you should just declare it as such.

Answer (score 0):

If `AB`, `AB`, and `ABC` are just *interfaces* and none of them add any `new` function to them, then why not write:

```
class Concrete4: public ABC
```

instead of

```
class Concrete4: public AC, public AB, public ABC
```

Are they not the same thing?

Of course, if the derived interfaces add new functions to it, then they're not same!

---

Similarly, you can write `ABC` in terms of `AB` and `C` instead of `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
 //class ABC: public A, public B, public C
   class ABC: public AB, public C
```

Note : I'm assuming that `A`,`B`,`C`, `AB`,`AC`, and `ABC` are all interfaces. i.e  they all contain pure virtual functions without defining them. And none of them add any new function to itself, besides having functions from base interface(s).

Comment: if I have class Concrete4: public ABC and class ABC: public A, public B, public C then I *cannot* do AB* ab = &concrete4; (VS2008) :-(

Comment: your second solution would work in the case mentioned above, but not if I need an "AC" at some other point.

Comment: @Philip: but why derive `ABC` from `A, B, C` in the first place?  If `class ABC : public AB, public C`, then you can write `AB* ab= &concrete4`

Comment: @Philipp: wherever you need `AC`, you can use `ABC` instead. I mean write `void fun(ABC *impl)` instead of `void fun(AC *impl)`

Comment: please see my second comment.